# single line if else in python dictionary comprehension method

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I just tried a list comprehension like this

```
[i if i==0 else i+100 for i in range(0,3)]
```

and it worked, but when I tried a similar dict comprehension, it throws an error:

```
d={3:3}
{d[i]:0 if i==3 else d[i]:True for i in range(0,4) }
```

What could be the reason? How can I use dict comprehension using `if else`?

The error this produces:

```
    {d[i]:0 if i==3 else d[i]:True for i in range(0,4) }
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note: The example I used here is just a random one, not my actual code.
I can do this with alternative an solution, but I'm only looking at dict comprehensions now to learn.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using a [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). It can only be used in places that accept expressions.

In a dictionary comprehension, the key and value parts are **separate** expressions, separated by the `:` (so the `:` character is *not* part of the expressions). You can use a conditional expression in each one of these, but you can't use one for both.

You only need to use it in the value part here:

```
{d[i]: 0 if i == 3 else True for i in range(4)}
```

However, you'll get a `KeyError` exception because the `d` dictionary has no `0`, `1`, and `2` keys.

See the [*Dictionary displays* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) of the expression reference documentation:

> ```
> dict_display       ::=  “{” [key_datum_list | dict_comprehension] “}”
> [...]
> dict_comprehension ::=  expression “:” expression comp_for
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> A dict comprehension, in contrast to list and set comprehensions, needs two expressions separated with a colon followed by the usual “for” and “if” clauses.

Comment: But So I can't use list comprehension if my declared dict dont have the keys? like you mentioned  "However, you'll get a KeyError exception because the d dictionary has no 0, 1, and 2 keys" ?

Comment: @syam: what has this got to do with a list comprehension?  You have an expression defining the key, `d[i]`. That expression will fail for `i = 0`, there is no `d[0]`. Only `d[3]` exists.

Comment: Compare this to a regular `for` loop: first `result = {}`, then `for i in range(4):`, and in the loop body `key = d[i]`, `value = 0 if i == 3 else True`, `result[key] = value`. That's exactly what the dict comprehension does, but without the names `result`, `key` and `value` actually being used. `key = d[i]` fails because there is no `d[0]`.

Comment: Thanks Buddy!. well explanation

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for *dict comprehension with `if-else`* problem:

```
dict((x, x ** 2) if x > 0 else (x, -x ** 2) for x in range(-4, 5))
```